# Limits similar to fundamental trigonometric limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x} = 1$. Can we assure that $\lim_{g(x)\to0}\frac{f(g(x))}{g(x)} = 1$? If we can't, what are the necessary conditions that g must satisfy so that this is indeed true?

Comment: One does not write like $\lim_{g(x) \to 0}$. What you probably wish to know is that whether $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(g(x))}{g(x)}=1$. This holds if $g(x) \to 0,g(x)\neq 0$ as $x\to 0$. This follows by rule for limit of composite functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. This is seen easily by the substitution $t=g(x)$. The limit will then be $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(t)}{t} = 1$.